# SharePoint 2010 Crawl Rules to crawl specific libraries inside a URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

I want to crawl specific libraries inside a URL and want to skip everything else in SharePoint 2010 Search.
For example - Under URL http://example.com,
I want to crawl

- Document Library http://example.com/doclib1 - Rule - http://example.com/doclib1/* include
- Document Library http://example.com/doclib2 - Rule - http://example.com/doclib2/* include

and want to skip everything else with the rule - http://example.com/* exclude

But it is not working and full crawl ends in 2 minutes with 0 success result

Comment: Why do you need this crawl rule? Just wondering.

Comment: We just do not want all the lists, libraries, & sub webs to be searchable other than the specific mentioned. I hope that answers. 
Do you have an answer to the problem?

Comment: What happens when you test the rules in the UI? What are you seeing in the Crawl Logs?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to only crawl special libraries. 
As an suggestion, you can create search scope to limit search results from special document libraries.